# What is the easiest way to obtain a value by looking for a specific heade with awk?

Tags: awk

I want to obtain the value that is under the header count (2500)
but the line number of the file can change

I tried with this

```
value=$(awk 'NR==6' $log_file)
echo $value
```

Also

```
value=$(awk 'NR==1' | awk '/^[0-9]+/ { print }' $log_file)
echo $value
```

log_file

```
PC220 - Production on Feb 13
Connected ...
CONNECT to DB
count
-------------------- 
2500                    
1 rows affected

Good bye!
User "BILL" disconnect successfully.
FIN
```

I want to get the value of 2500 that is below the count header

Comment: `awk '$0 == "count"{getline;getline;print}' $log_file`?

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk '$0 == "count" {n = NR+2} NR == n {print; exit}' file

2500
```

Just save line number when we get `count` record and print the value when we get 2nd records afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

shorter with `sed`

```
$ value=$(sed -n '/^count$/{n;n;p;q}' file)
```

find the header, next line, next line, print, quit.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a line that is equal to `count` and then get the first field of the second line below with

```
awk '$0 == "count"{getline;getline;print $1;exit}' $log_file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/CDep2z):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='PC220 - Production on Feb 13
Connected ...
CONNECT to DB
count
-------------------- 
2500                    
1 rows affected

Good bye!
User "BILL" disconnect successfully.
FIN'
awk '$0 == "count"{getline;getline;print $1;exit}' <<< "$s"
# => 2500
```